# azure Data Factory Pagination

Tags: postman, azure-data-factory

I am calling an API using Azure Data Factory and this requires pagination. The source is the REST endpoint and the output is CSV in Data Lake Storage Gen2.

I tried this API in Postman and this is what i am looking for:
[image]

The Response Header from the API consists of the Link Key which has the rel="first", rel="current", rel="next" and rel="last".

How can i do the same in Azure ADF call where i implement pagination for rel="next"?

Comment: Is [pagination support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support) what you are looking for?

Comment: There aren't many great examples around re use of `Headers` in pagination but I suggest you try running it first and see what problems you hit, eg does it only return the first page, or does it never finish etc.  It would also be useful to see a better example of the JSON being returned - please anonymise anything you want to in terms of links, but I'd like to see some **sample** JSON, not a muddy screenprint.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to official doc for [Pagination support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting RFC9588 to TRUE in the Pagination rules worked for me. According to Microsoft  it's True by default, but I wasn't able to get more than 30 records at a time until I set it to True explicitly.

[image: Image of RFC9588 to TRUE in ADF]